# scan folders and subfolders for a specific file then return the path

Tags: php, file, search, directory

I have a server with a lot of folders, sub-folders, and sub-sub-folders. 
I want to make a search.php page that would be used to search the whole server for a specific file. If the file is found, then return the location path to display a download link.
If two files with the exact same name is found in 2 different folders, return only 1 download link.

I came across many similar questions on this site but no solutions to do exactly what i want to do.

I'm also concerned about the speed. Would it drastically slow down a small dedicated server with medium traffic if the file has to scan through a few dozens folders with around 6000 files in total ? Using database is not an option

Is there a function i could use to do that ?

Comment: Probably the easiest thing to do would be use `grep` or similar, and interpret the results with your PHP script.

Comment: i don't know what is grep or how to use it. i'm looking for a pure PHP solution

Comment: `grep` is good. You could use PHP's `glob` or `scandir` recursively to search. Performance shouldn't be a problem, but it depends on how many files and folders you have. You could build a list in a text file (a simple cache) and scan that, which would be faster. You'd need to recreate the list if the files or folders changed, but that's probably not as frequent as the search.

Comment: i'm testing glob atm but i don't understand how to get it to scan the subfolders...